# DayJS isValid behaves differently to Moment

Tags: javascript

I was trying to validate birthday using `dayjs` but its `isValid` is returning `true` for a date that doesn't exist. Funnily enough, the `isValid` by `moment` is working just fine.

```
dayjs('2019/02/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD').isValid() // true
moment('2019/02/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD').isValid() // false
```

I can't switch to `moment` because of the lightweightness of `dayjs`

Any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: it's a bug, you can see [here](https://issuehunt.io/r/iamkun/dayjs/issues/605)

Comment: @RapSherlock My date is parsed correctly in both libraries though

Comment: or here https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/320

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please look at [this thread](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/320). Basically `isValid` doesn't validate if passed date is exists, it just validates that date was parsed correctly.

I'm not exactly sure if this works in all scenarios (especially if you have localization), but you could try something like:

```
function validate(date, format) {
  return dayjs(date, format).format(format) === date;
}

validate('2019/02/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD') // false
```

Reason for this kind of check is that

```
dayjs('2019/02/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
```

returns `2019/03/03`. Then when you compare it to your initial date (you should be able because formatting is the same) you should get the same value - and in this case you don't.

Answer (score 12):

**August 2021**: It's now possible to detect with `.isValid()` method these invalid dates passing a third parameter as true to `dayjs` constructor:

```
dayjs('2019/02/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD').isValid() // true
dayjs('2019/02/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD',true).isValid() // false
```

More information on this strict parsing argument can be found now at [official doc](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format).

NOTE: In `Node.js` I had to load first `customParseFormat` plugin before calling isValid() to receive expected validity results:

```
const dayjs = require("dayjs");
var customParseFormat = require("dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat");
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use customParseFormat plugin from day.js
I do this on my react project and this is work perfectly fine.

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);

dayjs('30-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY', true).isValid() // false
```

Comment: I need this also in my Vuejs project for this to work.  Thanks adif.

Answer (score 1):

**How moment.isValid() works (overflow checks)**

> If the moment that results from the parsed input does not exist, moment#isValid will return false.

**How dayjs.isValid() works**

If you look at the source code:

*src/index.js*

```
this.$d = parseDate(cfg) // Line 75
// ...
isValid() { // Line 96
  return !(this.$d.toString() === C.INVALID_DATE_STRING)
}
```

*src/constant.js*

```
export const INVALID_DATE_STRING = 'Invalid Date'
```

If you look to the source *parse* is not a straighforward `Date.parse()` because it take in consideration locale, date format and so on, but it seems that every valid date passed to Date() or Date.parse() are *valid*.

```
Date.parse('2019/02/31') // 1551567600000
new Date(2019/02/31) // Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Answer (score 0):

use strict mode

```
dayjs('2019/02/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD', true).isValid() //false
```

[image]

When strict mode is not enforced
[image]

**Note:** you have to extend `customParseFormat` plugin as a prerequisite

Comment: Not sure which version you are using but this does not work for me (v1.11.3). returns true instead

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa, Please see the attached browser debug screenshots in the answer. It is working fine in dayJS v1.11.3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can't rely on `isValid()` function that is provided in `dayjs`.

What I did, was to create a file utils called `date-utils.ts`. This file is a wrapper around the lib and add more validations on top of it.

Essentially, this statement will do the work we need:

```
  // it validates the string date properly
  if (Number.isNaN(new Date(date).getTime())) {
    return false;
  }
```

Then, you could create a file like the typescript example (feel free to make it js if you want).

```
// date-utils.ts
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

const isValid = (date: string) => {
  if (!date) {
    return false;
  }

  // it validates the string date properly
  if (Number.isNaN(new Date(date).getTime())) {
    return false;
  }

  return dayjs(date).isValid();
};

const getDate = (date: string) => {
  if (!date) {
    throw Error('The date is required.');
  }

  if (!isValid(date)) {
    throw Error(`The date "${date}" is not valid.`);
  }

  return dayjs(date);
};

export default { isValid, getDate };
```